# getUser always returns 0 when Facebook app installed on Symfony2 with PHP SDK

Tags: facebook, symfony, facebook-php-sdk

When I login the page just refreshes. When I echo the signed_request or userId, I just get 0. The weird thing is, it sometimes seems to work. I'm using FB PHP SDK 3.2.3 with symfony 2. On the page that loads before the one that returns 0, it also works.

```
    $facebook = new \Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'SECRET',
    'cookie' => true
    ));

    $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
    print_r($signed_request);
    $userId = $facebook->getUser();
    echo $userId;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I just fixed it. On the first page I get the access token that's being used. I store it in a session.

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$session->set('access_token', $access_token);
```

On the other page I retrieve the session and set the access token

```
$access_token = $session->get('access_token');
$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
```